# tikzscale does not work with the Beamer class

Tags: beamer, tikzscale

I couldn't get tikzscale work with the Beamer document class.

Here is a minimal example:

**Main.tex**:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Test.tikz}
    \end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

**Test.tikz**:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This produces the following errors:

```
line 9: Missing \endcsname inserted \end{frame}
line 9: pgfkeys: I do not know the key '/tikzscale/width=\linewidth ' and I am going to
```

If I change to another document class and remove the "frame"-environment all works fine.

I use a updated TeX-Live 2012 on Windows 7 x64.
My used version of tikzscale is v0.2.2

Edit: After a bug-report to the package author the problem is now fixed. :-)

Comment: Do you mind answering your question or closing this as *too localized*?

Comment: The MWE, above, does not compile for me using XaLaTeX, but does using LuaLaTeX